# HEVC: How to define maximum slice size

Tags: encoding, configuration-files, hevc

I'm trying to define slice's maximum size through parameters of the configuration file.

I set

```
SliceMode : 2
SliceArgument : 500
```

but I don't get the corresponding results:

```
105080 bits 
81616 bits 
24256 bits
3752 bits 
168 bits
128 bits 
10488 bits
160 bits
216 bits
73792 bits
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need to specify what program you're using

Comment: @OMGtechy I'm using HM 15.0

Comment: How you have got your results? NAL loss simulater??
if so,the NAL loss simulater just can identify the first slice of every picture.

Comment: @fgbin I got the results from HM 15.0 encoder.